# Jquery selector not working after append

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a php script that I call that returns html in a way that it can be directly inserted into a container or the body and just work (E.X. `'<image id="trolleyLogoEdge" class="pictureFrame party" src="tipsyTrixy.png" >'`). After appending this text to a `div` the selector `$('#pictureFrame > img:first')` won't work. I'm not using event handlers or anything so I don't know why I'm having an issue. My code worked fine when I just had the image tags in the `div` without any manipulation so I'm assuming it must be a selector issue. I have tested my php output and it is exactly matching the html that was in the `div` before I decided to dynamically populate the div.

```
        var classType = '';
        var classTypePrev = '';
        var width = $(window).width();
        var height = $(window).height();

        var size = (height + width)/2;
        var time = 0;
        $( document ).ready(function()
        {

            $.post( "pictureDirectory.php", function( data ) 
            {
                $('#picureFrame').append(data);
                startSlideshow($('#pictureFrame > img:first'));
            });

        });
        window.onresize = function() 
        {
            width = $(window).width();
        };
        function startSlideshow(myobj) 
        {


            classType = $(myobj).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
            if(classTypePrev != classType)
            {
                $('.picDescription').animate({'opacity': "0"},{duration: 2000,complete: function() {}});
                $('.picDescription.' + classType).animate({'opacity': "1"},{duration: 3000,complete: function() {}});
            }
            classTypePrev = classType;
            myobj.animate({left: "-=" + ((width/2)+ ($(myobj).width()/2) - 150), opacity: '1'},{
                duration: 5000,
                'easing': 'easeInOutCubic',
                complete: function() {}}).delay(2000).animate({left: "-=" + ((width/2)+ ($(myobj).width()/2) + 150), opacity: '0'},{
                    duration: 5000,
                    'easing': 'easeInOutCubic',
                    complete: function() 
                    {
                        $(myobj).css("left", "100%");
                    }
            });
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                var next = $(myobj).next();
                if (!next.length) 
                {
                    next = myobj.siblings().first();
                }
                startSlideshow(next)},9000);  
            }
```

Comment: You should never have the same name as an ID and a class on the same page. Since the img has the class `pictureFrame` and you in the selector are looking at an element with the ID `pictureFrame`.

Comment: Result of: `$('#pictureFrame > img').length` ??? BTW, i guess your markup are not exactly the same, you should provide a sample of it

Comment: I have images that are in different categories. All pictures have the class picture frame for css purposes and an additional class for their category. `.length()` tells me whether or not it's the last sibling so I can start my loop over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code that appends the data to the frame has a typo in the ID selector.

```
$.post( "pictureDirectory.php", function( data ) 
{
    $('#picureFrame').append(data);
             ^^here
    startSlideshow($('#pictureFrame > img:first'));
});
```

It should probably be

```
$('#pictureFrame').append(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` gets the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements.

`>` selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".
Try:

```
startSlideshow($("#pictureFrame").find("img:first"));
```

If `img` is not direct child of `#pictureFrame`, `.find()` should work.

Comment: ya could be a solution if img not direct child of #pictureFrame

Comment: A little explanation of this solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should know the difference between

> Delegated Event
>
> Direct Event

check [this](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for the difference between direct and delegated events.

If we were to click our newly added item, nothing would happen. This is because of the directly bound event handler that we attached previously. Direct events are only attached to elements at the time the .on() method is called. In this case, since our new anchor did not exist when .on() was called, it does not get the event handler.

check this [link](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#example) to official JQuery Document for further clarification.